# How can the html tag ID be undefined in this jsfiddle?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, cordova

I have a Phonegap application using some standard HTML and JQuery for showing data to the user. While testing on a Samsung Galaxy Camera 2 we occasionally get an error that a variable is 'undefined'.

This doesn't seem possible since the variable is created from what it thinks is undefined.

I am getting the error on fld[0].id:

> Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined.

Full example on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8lug/fu2v62fh/
Partial example javascript:

```
var fld = $('#thisdiv').find('[id^=fld-One]');

if (fld.length > 0 && fld[0].id.indexOf('#')) {
    $('#fld-Result').text("Success");
}
```

How is it possible this indexOf could break?

Edit:
Can someone offer an edit that protect this scenario in the IF statement?

Comment: Where is this script wrapped? As far as I know the only chance it has to be undefined is if the element fld-One does not (or does not **yet**) exist.

Comment: @briosheje Then `fld.length > 0` would be false and `.indexOf()` won't be called at all

Comment: @Andreas: Clever, indeed. So may it really be related to the browser's version / the browser itself? I don't think there really is any other possible reason.

Comment: but may be fd is an array but it's first element does not have property id, and is this way of accessing id fine?

Comment: This line of code would have been used a million times by now.  So it typically works.  fld is defined as an array of things with "id".  Can index "0" zero somehow not exist?  Maybe I should try a jquery .first()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting checks and balances that should protect from this situation.  If anyone can give a nicer syntax that would be fine to see.

```
var fld = $('#thisdiv').find('[id^=fld-One]');

if (fld.length > 0
  && fld[0] !== undefined
  && fld[0].id !== undefined
  && fld[0].id.indexOf('#')) {
    $('#fld-Result').text("Success");
}
```

Basically making sure both the object and the property exists before trying to reference it.